# iOS nkreipke/FTPManager : how to reduce timeout?

Tags: ios, ftp

I've recently posted a question about reducing the timeout of an FTP connection ([click here to see it if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292936/ios-how-to-reduce-an-ftp-connection-timeout)).

Now, I've been asked to post a more specific question, focusing on the component we're using for the FTP download.

We're using Nico Kreipke's FTPManager ([click here to go to its GitHub](https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager)).

What we're trying to implement is to download data from an FTP address, and if it fails we'll fallback to use an HTTPS web server.

When the FTP address we give isn't available, it takes about one minute to timeout.

The question is, how can I reduce that timeout?

Best regards,
Tiago

**Some More Info**

I forgot to say, the FTP connection is done with an IP (local network).

**Johan's Tip**

I added a property to FTPManager, a `double` named `timeout`.

Then I've overridden the accessor of `serverReadStream`, a property used throughout FTPManager to hold the read stream, so that it would configure the timeout interval for all requests.

```
- (NSInputStream *)serverReadStream
{
    return _serverReadStream;
}

- (void)setServerReadStream:(NSInputStream *)serverReadStream
{
    if ((_serverReadStream = serverReadStream)) {
        CFNumberRef number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &_timeout);
        CFReadStreamSetProperty((__bridge CFReadStreamRef)(_serverReadStream), _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout, number);
        CFRelease(number);
    }
}
```

`_kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout` is defined by:

```
#define _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout CFSTR("_kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout")
```

However, it still takes about one minute to timeout. I set the timeout before connecting to the FTP address, right after creating `ftpManager`. The code I use to set the timeout follows:

```
FTPManager *ftpManager = [[FTPManager alloc] init];
[ftpManager setTimeout:10];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with a custom method that checks whether the connection has already been established and data could be received, otherwise calls `[ftpManager abort]`?

Not a real connection timeout and seems kinda dirty, but should do the job.

Comment: No I haven't, thanks Nico. I'm already out of the office, but I'll definitely try that monday. And thank you for this component ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by simply setting a property of CFReadStream. So you probably need to subclass the FTPManager.

The property is called _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout.

```
#define _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout CFSTR("_kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout")
```

Then add this to appropriate method.

```
    double timeout = 30;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef)[[server.destination ftpURLForPort:server.port] URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]);

    CFNumberRef number = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &timeout);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout, number);
    CFRelease(num);
```

Comment: Wow! I really didn't expected someone'd answer. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, it didn't work :( CFReadStreamSetProperty throws an exception, "ftp stream failed: general stream error (check credentials?)".

Comment: My bad :( The exception was a me forgetting to check if the read stream was nil... However, I was unable to make it work. I'll be updating my questing with more detail.